# Calculate eccentricity with altitude and semiminor axes

Tags: orbital-elements, orbital-mechanics

Following on from [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/calculate-apsides-without-knowing-eccentricity), I wish to know how to find the *reverse* - how to find eccentricity given a Semi-minor axis & altitude.

I want to use something based on

$$b=a\sqrt{1−e^2}$$

but I have no real way to solve for $e$, for I do not trust my answer,

$$e=a\sqrt{1}-b$$

could anyone please help?

Comment: I assume that by altitude you mean $a$, the length of the semimajor axis?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did your math wrong.  I'll write out the steps for you:

Square both sides:
$b^2=a^2(1-e^2)$

Divide by $a^2$: 
$\frac{b^2}{a^2}=1-e^2$

Isolate $e^2$:
$e^2=1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}$

Taking the square root results in a solution for eccentricity, based on the length of the semiminor and semimajor axes:

$e = \sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$

Comment: I'm currently writing a TI-BASIC program, and this will help tremendously. another question though: how would one do

Comment: 12rv=πab/P for b?

Comment: made a mistake, 1/2rv=πab/P.

Comment: @RoryYammomoto What do you want to solve that one for?  Which variable?

Comment: Oh, for b.  That one will be $b=\frac{2\pi a}{Prv}$

Comment: you can substitute that into the equation for $e$ to get $e=\sqrt{1-(\frac{2\pi}{Prv})^2}$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46805/discussion-between-rory-yammomoto-and-phiteros).

Comment: this does not seem to work. It turns out my original answer for (1/2)RV=πAB/P for B, (((1/2)RVP)/(πA)) was correct enough.